# Is a local ring Artinian, if the maximal ideal is nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, artinian

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203701/312406) suggests the idea, that a local ring $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ whose maximal ideal is nilpotent is in fact an Artinian ring.

Is this true? If so, how is it proven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need that $R$ is noetherian, else there are counterexamples.

E.g., take $R = K[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}/(x_i | i \in \mathbb{N})^2$.

If $R$ is Noetherian, this is a special case of [Lemma 10.59.4 here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KD) which states that a Noetherian ring of dimension $0$ is Artinian.

Comment: I just added a proof that $R$ has dimension zero, so I will not become confused (again) in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There is a version of this theorem even for noncommutative rings. It is called the [Hopkins-Levitzki theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem).

It says, in a nutshell, that if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple and $J(R)$ is nilpotent, then $R$ is right Artinian iff right Noetherian.  Yours is a special case where $R/J(R)$ is a field.

Here is the [DaRT search](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=21&H=23&L=63l&L=63r) which currently yields two examples of local, non-Artinian rings with nilpotent Jacobson radicals.